# Anylogic set forklift capacity to be 2

Tags: anylogic, capacity

I defined a forklift as an agent and also defined a TransportFleet for my forklifts. The default behavior is that one forklift can only transport one pallet. However, in my warehouse, the forklift can lift two pallets. How can I change the capacity of forklifts?

Comment: you have to batch the pallets

Comment: Thanks, Felipe. I have a follow-up question though. The batch component will wait until a batch of pallets has arrived. How can I create batches for the same product only? For example, if I have 5 pallets of one product came, I want to create three batches of 2, 2, and 1 pallets.

Comment: you answer is here: https://noorjax.com/2019/07/02/dynamic-batches/